# Weblogic11: User-specified log class 'org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger' cannot be found or is not useable

Tags: java, logging, weblogic11g, spring-4

I know that this error already appears on stackoverflow and normally it translates to a classpath problem. In my case this is my context:

Application Server: **Weblogic 10.3.6**

Using Spring 4 + log4j.

Weblogic User domain lib folder:

- log4j-1.2.17.jar
- commons-logging-1.1.3.jar
- spring-beans-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar
- spring-core-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar
- spring-jdbc-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar
- spring-tx-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar

When I try to use the StoredProcedure spring class (in the context of a Custom Weblogic Authenticator) I have this error:

```
<10/Fev/2015 17H27m GMT> <Error> <org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.internal.AdapterManager> <BEA-00
0000> <ServletContainerAdapter manager not initialized correctly.>
org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: User-specified log class 'org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger' cannot be found or is not useable.
        at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.discoverLogImplementation(LogFactoryImpl.j
ava:874)
        at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.newInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:604)
        at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:336)
        at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:310)
        at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:685)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.object.RdbmsOperation.<init>(RdbmsOperation.java:59)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.object.SqlCall.<init>(SqlCall.java:78)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.object.StoredProcedure.<init>(StoredProcedure.java:58)
```

I believe that this got something to do with the version of log4j or commons-logging (or eventually a dependency of Spring 4 that I'm missing.. like slf4j, althought I don't think this is required).

Does anyone has any ideas about this?

Thanks in advance

Best regards

João Simas

Comment: Did you try to copy both jars (log4j and commons-logging) to the server and add explicit reference in server start->classpath? Just to make sure if this is related to a missing jar or maybe a conflict.

Comment: Already tried, still same error. Added the commons-logging-1.1.3.jar with log4j jar to the AdminServer classpath.

Comment: Maybe there are two commons-logging around, perhaps this could help: https://community.oracle.com/thread/2498003

Comment: Are you using `<prefer-application-packages>` or `prefer-web-inf-classes`? I think you need it, weblogic already includes log4j on the classpath by default, so the version in your app is conflicting http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24368/classloading.htm#WLPRG282

Comment: The problem is that this is not in a Web Application context. There is no weblogic.xml for me to do that. This occurs in a Custom Authenticator Provider I've implemented. And when it started to get too complex I added spring... and then the logging issues started...

Comment: Ah - we are doing something similar... we ended up editing `startWebLogic.sh` to put our logging jar on the classpath directly (not domain lib folder) and got it working. You may need to turn on some class load debugging like: https://blogs.oracle.com/vijaya/entry/weblogic_classloader_debug_flags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks "Display Name is missing" for the provided link:
[http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24368/classloading.htm#WLPRG282][1]

The solution was creating a dedicated User Domain and redeploying the jars. Everything worked as expected.

João Simas